# How to configure an API for access token validation using OpenIddict

Tags: authentication, authorization, .net-6.0, introspection, openiddict

I am using the configuration examples of OpenIddict (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples), specifically the example of Zirku.Api1 for token validation through introspection and accessing the endpoints of this API in .Net 6.0. The identity server is not in the same solution.

Below, I'll show you how I have it configured.
In the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
                    .AddValidation(options =>
                    {
                        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:6001/");
                        
                        // Configure the validation handler to use introspection and register the client
                        // credentials used when communicating with the remote introspection endpoint.
                        options.UseIntrospection()
                               .SetClientId("testapp")
                               .SetClientSecret("6da97943-865d-41c4-970b-5a2670b7e347");
                        // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
                        options.UseSystemNetHttp();

                        // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                        options.UseAspNetCore();
                    });
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

and in the Configure method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/api", async context =>
                {
                    var user = context.User;
                    if (user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{user.Identity.Name} is allowed to access Api1.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
                    }
                }).RequireAuthorization(); // Requiere autorización

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<HubServer>("/hub");
            });
```

and in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public async Task<Utils.HttpResponse> listAll(int page = 1, int itemsPerPage = 10, string search = "")
        {...//more code
```

The issue must lie in the configuration of the API since when making a request through Insomnia (Postman), the Identity API responds correctly. However, when I make the request to the API, it tries to connect to the Identity API using 'https://localhost:6001/.well-known/openid-configuration' and fails, displaying the following error:

```
 OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
        "error": "server_error",
        "error_description": "The remote authorization server is currently unavailable or returned an invalid configuration.",
        "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2170"
      }.
```

if anyone could help me I will really appreciated

Comment: Does https://localhost:6001/.well-known/openid-configuration actually return anything if you try to access it directly in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for answer @Englund0110. It was a cryptography problem. I already resolved it.